# Are typeof(T) and this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] always equivalent within a generic class instance?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a covariantly-safe generic class that wraps another. I wish to make it simple to get the most-derived type available of the instance at run-time:

```
public interface IReference<out T> { Type UnderlyingType { get; } }

public class Reference<T> : IReference<T> where T : class
{
    public Type UnderlyingType => /*typeof(T)*/ this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

I'm pretty sure in the example above I can just use `typeof(T)` to make the implementation above faster - but I want to make sure this doesn't lead to cases where a compile-time type is returned that is different from what the run-time type might have been.

---

For example, if someone goes:

```cs
IReference<object> weak = new Reference<string>()
IdentifyReference(weak);

void IdentifyReference<T>(IReference<T> unknown) where T : class {
    Print(typeof(T));
    Print(unknown.UnderlyingType);
}
```

I want the following output:

```cs
object
string
```

Comment: If `Value` is null then it has no run-time type, only its compile-time type.

Comment: @JohnWu `Value` has no run-time type, but in this example I'm asking about the run-time type parameters of the `Reference<T>` instance.

Comment: The test fails in this case: `IdentifyReference(new Reference<object>("A string"));` , where at runtime underlying value is a child type (`string` here) of the generic constraint type `T` (`object` here). Unless constructor of Reference would not deal with this situation

Comment: @Renat - yes exactly, I'm aware that `unknown.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]` is unreliable from *outside* of the reference instance, which is why I wanted to implement something like `UnderlyingType`

Comment: Sorry, I can see that showing details surrounding my use of the inner `Value` was only causing confusion, so I've edited the post to focus on the actual question I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be sure that `typeof(T)` in the `UnderlyingType` property produces the runtime type, because of how polymorphism works.

There is simply not enough information at compile time for the compiler to figure out what `unknown.UnderlyingType` is. Keep in mind that `IReference` is an interface, so the compiler hasn't got the faintest idea of what concrete type `unknown` is. Therefore, it doesn't even know that this particular implementation should be executed:

```
public Type UnderlyingType => typeof(T) /*this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]*/;
```

As far as the compiler is concerned, it could be an implementation from `Foo`, which just so happens to implement `IReference<object>`.

Therefore, the expression `typeof(T)` is evaluated at runtime, when runtime polymorphism (dynamic dispatch chooses the right implementation) occurs. The way polymorphism works causes the expression to always be evaluated in the context of the runtime type.

Comment: Thanks, this is chain of logic I was looking for to confirm my understanding of how things would play out in practice.